# How to send msg on new channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
  const message = reactionReaction.message;
  const verifyChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get("684306214750126265");
  const member = message.author.id;
  const guild = message.guild;
  const memberos = message.member.displayName;

  if (user.bot) return;
  if (
    reactionReaction.emoji.name === "✔️" &&
    message.channel.id === verifyChannel.id
  ) {
    guild.channels.create(`TICKET + ${memberos}`, {
      type: "text",
      permissionOverwrites: [
        {
          id: message.author.id,
          allow: ["VIEW_CHANNEL", "SEND_MESSAGES"],
        },
      ],
    });
    await reactionReaction.users.remove(member).catch(console.error);
   message.reply({ embed: elo1 })
      .then(msg => {
         message.react('❌')
     })




  }
});
});
```

I create ticket bot, actualy creating channel working but sennding message on this channel no ;/
actualy message is sending on verifyChannel but i will send this on channel " TICKET + ${memberos} "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`guild.channels.create()` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) with the new Guild Channel, resolve this promise to send a message to the newly created channel.

```
const newChannel = await guild.channels.create(`TICKET + ${memberos}`, {
   type: "text",
   permissionOverwrites: [
      {
         id: message.author.id,
         allow: ["VIEW_CHANNEL", "SEND_MESSAGES"],
      },
   ],
});

newChannel.send('Hello World!');
```

Comment: Hello, I have one more question, why reaction didn't del channel ? ;/ ``` 
if (user.bot) return;
  if (
    reactionReaction.emoji.name === "❌" &&
    message.channel.id === newChannel.id ){
        newChannel.delete({
        timeout: 5000
      });
    }
    
  


  }
});
});
 ```

Comment: If you have another question please make another post, this will ensure you receive help and will help us better see your code and understand your problem